How can I get ElDoc to show documentation for the thing at point using a manual trigger?
I'm trying to figure out how to get ElDoc to show documentation for the thing at point with a manual trigger. What I would like is to be able to set eldoc-idle-delay to some high number and then bind a key to (eldoc-print-current-symbol-info) to get the same behavior as hover where documentation is shown in the minibuffer.
If I bind a key to (eldoc-print-current-symbol-info), eldoc opens the eldoc for ... buffer in a new window. I've tried with (eldoc-print-current-symbol-info nil) as well, but then no documentation is shown.
This is the only information I could find relating to the idea, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work anymore... or maybe I'm doing something wrong. This function does not seem to show any documentation.
Suggested function:
(defun eldoc-fancy (arg)
  "`eldoc' but uses the echo area by default and a prefix will swap to a buffer."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((eldoc-display-functions
          (if arg '(eldoc-display-in-buffer) '(eldoc-display-in-echo-area))))
    (eldoc t)))

https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/discussions/1328
Emacs 29.3 and ElDoc 1.15.0

Install eldoc-box package and  use eldoc-box-eglot-help-at-point or eldoc-box-help-at-point.  Even if these functions do NOT what they want, I hope the package has enough clues to cook up what you want to accomplish.

Thanks, but I wanted the default behavior of eldoc with the echo area / minibuffer.

This seems to work, with the important part being the modification to the first condition.
(defun +eldoc-display-in-echo-area (docs _interactive)
  "Adjusts `eldoc-display-in-echo-area' when checking `this-command'.

`eldoc-display-in-echo-area': Display DOCS in echo area. Honor
`eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p' and
`eldoc-echo-area-prefer-doc-buffer'."
  (cond
   (;; Check if we have permission to mess with echo area at all.  For
    ;; example, if this-command is non-nil while running via an idle
    ;; timer, we're still in the middle of executing a command, e.g. a
    ;; query-replace where it would be annoying to overwrite the echo
    ;; area.
    (or
     (not (eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p))
     (and this-command (not (eq this-command 'eldoc-manual))) ;; Modification
     (not (eldoc--message-command-p last-command))))
   (;; If we do but nothing to report, clear the echo area.
    (null docs)
    (eldoc--message nil))
   (t
    ;; Otherwise, establish some parameters.
    (let*
        ((width (1- (window-width (minibuffer-window))))
         (val (if (and (symbolp eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p)
                       eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p)
                  max-mini-window-height
                eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p))
         (available (cl-typecase val
                      (float (truncate (* (frame-height) val)))
                      (integer val)
                      (t 'just-one-line)))
         single-doc single-doc-sym)
      (let ((echo-area-message
             (cond
              (;; To output to the echo area, we handle the
               ;; `truncate-sym-name-if-fit' special case first, by
               ;; checking for a lot of special conditions.
               (and
                (eq 'truncate-sym-name-if-fit eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p)
                (null (cdr docs))
                (setq single-doc (caar docs))
                (setq single-doc-sym
                      (format "%s" (plist-get (cdar docs) :thing)))
                (< (length single-doc) width)
                (not (string-match "\n" single-doc))
                (> (+ (length single-doc) (length single-doc-sym) 2) width))
               single-doc)
              ((and (numberp available)
                    (cl-plusp available))
               ;; Else, given a positive number of logical lines, we
               ;; format the *eldoc* buffer, using as most of its
               ;; contents as we know will fit.
               (with-current-buffer (eldoc--format-doc-buffer docs)
                 (save-excursion
                   (eldoc--echo-area-substring available))))
              (t ;; this is the "truncate brutally" situation
               (let ((string
                      (with-current-buffer (eldoc--format-doc-buffer docs)
                        (buffer-substring (goto-char (point-min))
                                          (progn (end-of-visible-line)
                                                 (point))))))
                 (if (> (length string) width)  ; truncation to happen
                     (unless (eldoc--echo-area-prefer-doc-buffer-p t)
                       (truncate-string-to-width string width))
                   (unless (eldoc--echo-area-prefer-doc-buffer-p nil)
                     string)))))))
        (when echo-area-message
          (eldoc--message echo-area-message)))))))

(advice-add 'eldoc-display-in-echo-area :override '+eldoc-display-in-echo-area)

(defun +eldoc-print-current-symbol-info ()
  "`eldoc-print-current-symbol-info' but signals that this is a manual
trigger and allows use of the echo area."
  (interactive)
  (setq this-command 'eldoc-manual)
  (eldoc-print-current-symbol-info))

(eldoc-add-command 'eldoc-manual)

(setq eldoc-idle-delay 100)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") '+eldoc-print-current-symbol-info)

Explanation:
eldoc-display-in-echo-area stops execution if any of the following
are true:

eldoc-display-message-no-interference-p returns non-nil
this-command is set
eldoc--message-commands does not contain last-command

The function originally does not continue if this-command is set,
because that would mean a command is currently executing.

Check if we have permission to mess with echo area at all.  For
example, if this-command is non-nil while running via an idle
timer, we're still in the middle of executing a command, e.g. a
query-replace where it would be annoying to overwrite the echo
area.

Unfortunately what seems to happen is if eldoc-documentation-functions
is immediate, this-command is whatever called
eldoc-print-current-symbol-info. If eldoc-documentation-functions is
asynchronous, this-command is nil.
This means executing eldoc-print-current-symbol-info from a user
function works for asynchronous documentation functions (e.g. buffers with
eglot) but not from immediate documentation functions (e.g. buffers with
emacs lisp).
Adjusting this function so that it stops if this-command is set and
it is not the eglot-manual symbol keeps similar functionality while allowing
the function to execute from a user initiated request.
